# How well-known or documented are the events of Endgame to the general population?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame, wandavision

In *WandaVision* episode 5, the following exchange takes place:

> MONICA: Uh, she could've taken out Thanos on her own if he hadn't
> initiated a blitz. I mean, nobody else came close.
>
> JIMMY: Well, I'd argue that Captain Marvel came close.

Out of universe this is an obvious reference to some eye catching moments on the final battle of *Endgame*. For a spectator those are very good references, however in-universe those indicate an incredibly high level of detail of what happened. This contrasts a bit also with the musical depiction of the Battle of New York in *Hawkeye*, where he says Ant-Man wasn’t even there.

Are there any references (other than that), either in-universe or confirmation by the writers, on the level of details the general population have about the events on *Endgame*? Maybe the events were somehow recorded by Stark tech?

Comment: It seems like the events are pretty well known. The play in Hawkeye can be put down to artistic license. _Ms. Marvel_ has a lot of interesting information on this peppered through the first episode, for example, Scott apparently has a podcast.

Comment: I'd argue that Scott's podcast was probably part of why people added him to the *Avengers* New York battle. Basically, since he's the face of the facts, people assume he was there. Just small.

Comment: The winning side had many survivors.  They'd have told the story far and wide.

Comment: And while it’s not mentioned in-universe (or as far as I know, out of universe), it’s inconceivable that events like the battle in _Endgame_ wouldn’t be followed by government inquiries and extensive journalism to record and convey the events for the world and posterity. Most of the (named movie character) participants survive.

Comment: Also with regard to that exchange, Monica works for S.W.O.R.D., and Jimmy works for the FBI (and has experience with Ant-Man), so they might have more access to first-hand account or records than the general public would.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **The events are public knowledge.**

Scott Lang has written a book; *Look Out for the Little Guy!* which details his own life story. A copy of this book, written from an in-universe perspective '*by Scott Lang*' was [published by Marvel Entertainment in 2023](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C64RBMl04bc).

The book covers the events of *Infinity War*, as a second-hand account from Black Widow and Captain America's perspective, and the events of *Endgame*, told from Scott's own POV. It gives extensive details about Thanos, the Infinity Stones, the Snap, the time-heist and the Blip.

The (in-universe) book is apparently one of the bestselling books of recent times, with more than 10 million copies of the hardback edition sold worldwide.

[image]